# error code comes up when no error

Tags: python, random, dice

I'm trying to make a error message for my dice sim

```
import random
loop=1

while loop == 1:
 dice=input("Choose dice 4,6 or 12 sided")
 if dice =="4":
     n=random.randint(1,4)
     print(dice)
     print(n)
 if dice =="6":
     n=random.randint(1,dice)
     print(dice)
     print(n)
 if dice =="12":
     n=random.randint(1,dice)
     print(dice)
     print(n)

 else:
    print("Error")
```

error comes up for 4 and 6 but when i use the 12 sided no error comes up

```
Choose dice 4,6 or 12 sided4
4
4
Error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really state which programming language you're using. I'm assuming this is Python, but if it's not my answer might be wrong.

Your problem is that you need to be using `elif`, not if. You're also trying to implicitly convert between strings and integers, which doesn't work. This code should, unless I've missed something else.

```
import random
loop=1

while loop == 1:
 dice=input("Choose dice 4,6 or 12 sided")
 if dice =="4":
     n=random.randint(1,4)
     print(dice)
     print(str(n))
 elif dice =="6":
     n=random.randint(1,int(dice))
     print(dice)
     print(str(n))
 elif dice =="12":
     n=random.randint(1,int(dice))
     print(dice)
     print(str(n))
 else:
    print("Error")
```

Comment: thaks i was using python. question python guess if its a int,string,float or char so do i still need to tell the programe which one it is.

Comment: Python will guess which one it is when you define it, but converting between them (converting the string "73" to the integer 73 for instance) has to be done manually.

If my answer helped, please click the check mark button next to it to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `elif` instead of if, or a `switch` statement.

The code you provided says "if dice does not equal 12 then print Error".

Try something like:

```
while loop == 1:
 dice=input("Choose dice 4,6 or 12 sided")
 if dice =="4":
     n=random.randint(1,4)
     print(dice)
     print(n)
 elif dice =="6":
     n=random.randint(1,dice)
     print(dice)
     print(n)
 elif dice =="12":
     n=random.randint(1,dice)
     print(dice)
     print(n)
 else:
    print("Error")
```

This lets you break out of the loop early without evaluating every single expression.